# How to list the last modified files in a jar

Tags: shell, unix

I want to list the last modified files in a jar.

`jar -tvf kumar.jar | grep mtime+2`

Above command listing all the files in the jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sort`:

```
jar tvf kumar.jar | sort -k7,7 -k3,3M -k4,4 -k5,5 | tail -n <nb>
```

where `<nb>` is the number of last modified files you need. The idea being that since the output of `jar tvf ...` will give something like:

```
2341 Tue May 24 12:55:02 CEST 2016 ...
```

you want first to sort using the year (7th field), then the month (3rd field in human-readable format hence the `M`), then the day (4th field), and finally the time in hh:mm:ss format (5th field).